# How to set a domain on an axis and have the axis intervals not constant or take up different amount of interval spaces using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I'm trying to add a 2nd axis to a chart I'm creating, but the 2nd axis will not have constant intervals like in the image below.  Can the letter type axis be created, and can it be done by only adding one axis?

[image]

Comment: So you want to have only 4 ticks on the axis?

Comment: For this example sure, one tick per each letter type, but the interval for the 1st would be length 1 unit, and the 2nd would be 3, the 3rd would be 1, and the 4th would be 2.  This is just a simplified example of what I'm going to be doing.

Comment: D3 doesn't support this directly.

Comment: Thought so :(, do you know if theres a way to stop the domain from being unique?, so If I marked every individual letter with a letter type, the domain would be [v, c, c, c, v, c, c], but I believe d3 shortens it to [v, c]?

Comment: Again not something directly supported by D3 -- you could probably do it by generating unique values by adding a suffix and then stripping off that suffix in the `tickFormat` function for the axis.